# Prometheus Database Exporter giving Errorpingingoracle:="missing port in address

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle db exporter from https://github.com/iamseth/oracledb_exporter/releases linux version 5.1 and not using docker or similar for installation. When I am executing nohup ./oracledb_exporter &, I see a lot of errors in the log. I am already exporting the DATA_SOURCE_NAME

tried multiple methods of exporting DATA_SOURCE_NAME, one of the method is

```
export DATA_SOURCE_NAME="system/Password#123@myhostname:1523//oracle/ORCLDB"
export DATA_SOURCE_NAME="oracle://system:Password#123@myhostname:1523/ORCLDB"
ts=2023-08-31T08:08:25.130Z caller=default_metrics.go:81 level=error therewasanissuewhileloadingspecifieddefaultmetricsfileat:default-metrics.toml,proceedingtorunwithdefaultmetrics.="open default-metrics.toml: no such file or directory"
ts=2023-08-31T08:08:25.130Z caller=collector.go:262 level=error Errorpingingoracle:="missing port in address"
ts=2023-08-31T08:08:25.130Z caller=main.go:70 level=info msg="Starting oracledb_exporter" version="(version=, branch=, revision=3c12d9edaff0fd7838743a3f9243b2161ed7ebf1)"
ts=2023-08-31T08:08:25.131Z caller=main.go:71 level=info msg="Build context" build="(go=go1.19.4, platform=linux/amd64, user=, date=, tags=unknown)"
ts=2023-08-31T08:08:25.131Z caller=main.go:72 level=info msg="Collect from: " metricPath=/metrics
ts=2023-08-31T08:08:25.131Z caller=tls_config.go:274 level=info msg="Listening on" address=[::]:9161
ts=2023-08-31T08:08:25.131Z caller=tls_config.go:277 level=info msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false address=[::]:9161
ts=2023-08-31T08:08:32.502Z caller=collector.go:262 level=error **Errorpingingoracle:="missing port in address"**
```

I am not finding what I am doing wrong, I am running the exporter on the database server itself, so that I don't have to install any separate Oracle basic client.

I just downloaded the exporter and executed it from the database server.

If someone can share the steps for non-docker installation